# html5 canvas remove vertical/horizontal line worth of pixel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am implementing a seam carving algorithm for picture frames.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving

I know this algorithm is not very good, because it slices a straight seam from a picture, however the good news is that i am doing this for, "Picture frames", so you can imagine it will work just fine.

So if the image is 100 pixels in width, i would like to remove the a vertical line at the 50th pixel.Then it will be 99 pixels in width.

Here is the pseudo, I removed my previous code attempt

1. Load an image to a canvas.
2. Remove a vertical line which has a width of 1 pixel and height equal to the loaded image.If that image had a width equal to 100, it will now be 99.
3. Get Base64 encoded string of the new processed image.

What i want to do is remove a vertical line that has a width of 1 pixel and height equal to the image, and then draw the image to a canvas and get base64 encoded image.

Comment: Please add the comment statements in your code as a properly formatted question in the text body above.

Comment: What i want to do is remove a vertical line that has a width of 1 pixel and height equal to the image, and then draw the image to a canvas and get base64 encoded image.

Comment: Please reread my edited comment (sry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.Notice i am using Caman, so when loading the image i do not lose quality and the browser's thread is not blocked due to caman non blocking thread model.

https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS

This can probably be done in a webworker, the for loop that does the iteration of pixels anyways.

If anybody has a more efficient way to do this, please make a suggestion, i will probably do that in the future but i do not have the time for that right now.

```
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    canvas.height = 200;
    canvas.width = 200;
    Caman(canvas, "download.png", function () {



    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var oldid = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 360, 360);

    var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var newContext2d = newCanvas.getContext("2d");


    newCanvas.width = 360;
    newCanvas.height = 340;

    var vnewid = newContext2d.createImageData(360, 360);


    var oldArray = Array.from(oldid.data);

    console.log(oldArray);

    var arrayToInsert = [];

    for (var y = 0; y < 360; ++y) {

        for (var x = 0; x < 360; ++x) {
            if (y > 90 && y < 110) { // this is how we remove a horizontal line worth of 20 pixels in width.

            } else {
                var index = (y * 360 + x) * 4; // index of the current pixel
                arrayToInsert.push(oldArray[index]);
                arrayToInsert.push(oldArray[index + 1]);
                arrayToInsert.push(oldArray[index + 2]);
                arrayToInsert.push(oldArray[index + 3]);
            }
        }
    }

    vnewid.data.set(arrayToInsert);
    newContext2d.putImageData(vnewid, 0, 0, 0, 0, 360, 340);

    var newC = newCanvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(newC); 

    // take this console.log base64 and put it here.

   // https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
});
```

Here is the html

```
   <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="camanjs.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img width="200" height="200" id="f1img" src="download.png" />
            <div >
                <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

            </div>

            <script src="index.js"></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the original image as source and then setup the canvas to final size, for example:

```js
var img=new Image; img.onload=carve; img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/OqB5r.jpg";

function carve() {
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var cut = 50;        // we remove [50, 50 + carveWidth>, in this case
  var carveWidth = 16; // exaggerated to show noticeable change
  
  // set final size of canvas:
  c.width = this.width - carveWidth;
  c.height = this.height;
  
  // draw in first half using clip arguments of drawImage()
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, cut, this.height, 0, 0, cut, this.height);

  // draw in second half, notice we skip cut+carve for source, but not for dest.
  ctx.drawImage(this, cut + carveWidth, 0, this.width, this.height,
                      cut             , 0, this.width, this.height);
                      
  // save out canvas
}
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid red} /* to show actual canvas size */
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

For the algorithm you would need to do something similar but to use the carving path as a mask for the first half:

- Draw in image (complete) at the destination size
- Use composite mode to remove irregular seem using closed path clipping out the second half
- Use composite mode destination-over
- Draw in image minus offset for seam - this will be drawn behind the first half making a complete image

Repeat for each seam.

Comment: I really tried to understand what you want to say, but i am unable to do so.Spent over an hour.Nothing.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Anything specific you didn't understand?